# Clearing html document with BeautifulSoup and multiple paragraphs

Tags: html, linux, bash, text

I have a html document, which I could get its elements using BeautifulSoup, and extract the text. But my problem is that trying to get the body of the document using the "getText()" method, it merges all the paragraphs and returns one line. I tried different ways to get separate paragraphs, but no success, yet.
The format of the document is:

```
<div class="body" style="text-align: justify;padding: 20px;">   <div align="justify"><span style="font-weight: bold; color: rgb(128, 0, 0);"><img style="border: medium none; margin-left: 10px;" alt="" title="" src="/files/7/7/86119_216.jpg" align="right">ABC-</span>Paragraph 1<br><br>Paragraph  2<br><br>Paragraph  3<br><br><span style="font-weight: bold;">Paragraph  4</span><br>Paragraph  5 <span style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline; color: rgb(128, 0, 0);">Paragraph 6</span>Paragraph <br><br>Paragraph</div> <div class="wrapper"></div> </div>  </div>
```

what I currently use for getting the body of this document is:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup( page )
body = soup.find("div", {"class":"body"})
```

Till here everything is ok. My problem now is how to get the paragraphs in the body.
Any ideas?

---

Trying to process another html file, I got another problem for extracting the paragraphs. The format of this new page is:

```
<div class="detailCont">
    <span>News agency:</span>
    <h2>
        Header

    </h2>
        <div>
            <img class="showNewsImg" src="http://images.agency.com/images/position36/2013/9/khrid_hvapyma-910407-as.jpg" />
        </div>

    <div class="lead">
        <span>additional info</span>-
        agency:<br />Paragraph 1
    </div>

    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3</p>
    <p>Paragraph 4</p>
    <p>Paragraph 5</p>
    </div>
```

all the data that I need are in this part. So I can get this part using the following command:

```
doc = soup.find("div", {"class":"detailCont"})
```

Which contains both the hear and the body.
For getting the header I use the following command:

```
header = doc.h2
```

but I don't know how I can get just the body.
Any ideas?
bests.

Comment: `<br>` isn't strictly speaking a paragraph separator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
[s for s in body.strings if s.strip() != '']
```

It yields:

```
['ABC-',
 'Paragraph 1',
 'Paragraph  2',
 'Paragraph  3',
 'Paragraph  4',
 'Paragraph  5 ',
 'Paragraph 6',
 'Paragraph ',
 'Paragraph']
```